# reset paginator first page angular material

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to go to the first page of the mat-paginator, that is, reset the pagination, but it does not work. Any idea how it can be solved?

My html is such that

```
<mat-paginator [length]="itemTotal" [pageIndex]="page" [pageSize]="itemPage" (page)="pageEvent = getPublicationFollowersData($event)">
    </mat-paginator>
```

The typescript:

```
   getPublicationFollowersData(event?: PageEvent) {
      this.getPublicationsUser(event.pageIndex);
}
```

and i try to initialize the page with:

```
this.page = 1
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to use a `ViewChild` decorator to select the paginator and then set the `pageIndex` property of the paginator.

```
@ViewChild() paginator: MatPaginator;
...
this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
```

Edit: As suggested by the other answers, if you would like to reset the paginator to the first page, it would be better to use `this.paginator.firstPage()`

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I have an error :
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'pageIndex' of undefined`

Comment: this.paginator.firstPage() also works if you want to be explicit as hell.

Comment: add setTimeout function , 'pageIndex' issue did not ,

setTimeout(()=>{
this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
});

Comment: if you don't want to emit a PageEvent, it's better to use the first example.

Answer (score 15):

```
<mat-paginator #paginator [length]="length"
               [pageSize]="pageSize"
               [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
               (page)="pageEvent = paginationClicked($event)">
</mat-paginator>
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
this.paginator.firstPage();
```

Answer (score 11):

Create a referecne for material angular paginator along with data source

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

You want to reset the paginator using the following code

```
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

You can also reset by calling the first page method of the paginator

```
this.paginator.firstPage();
```

Answer (score 1):

if using

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static : true} ) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

it should be

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static : false} ) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

if static:true the paginator object is undefined.

Comment: I have undefined error with  { static : false} :(

Comment: This depends on the template it's written on, and is not required in the latest versions of angular

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;

 this.paginator.firstPage();

<mat-paginator #paginator [length]="length"
           [pageSize]="pageSize"
           [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
           (page)="pageEvent = paginationClicked($event)">
```

now you can reset the pagination using below

```
    setTimeout(()=>{this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;});
```